# Bootstrap tooltip trigger options based on element type

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, input, focus, tooltip

I have this code:

```
$('body').tooltip({
    selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]',
    viewport: 'body',
    delay: {
        show: 300,
        hide: 100
    },
    trigger: ($(this.$element).is('input')) ? 'focus' : 'hover'
});
```

but it doesn't work. I want to show tooltip on focus when the element is form input and on hover when is not form input element. But this still show tooltip on hover even if element is form input. I need to use selector option since I use tooltip on dynamic content.
What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `trigger` option only takes a string, and there is no reference available to 'this', you'd have to create separate tooltip selector instances like this..

```
$('body').tooltip({
  selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]:not("input")',
  viewport: 'body',
  delay: {
    show: 300,
    hide: 100
  },
  trigger: 'hover'
}).tooltip({
  selector: 'input',
  viewport: 'body',
  delay: {
    show: 300,
    hide: 100
  },
  trigger: 'focus'
});
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/tRzW28a0mH